# How to use a generic result as a generic parameter when the type is a wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

[UPDATE] The real situation was a bit more complicated than my initial question made it seem. I've changed the code a bit to reflect that.[/UPDATE]

I'm a bit stumped by the following behavior. Given code like:

```
interface Inter<T> {
  T makeT();
  void useT(T t);
}

public class Foo {
  public void bar(Qux q) {
    Inter<?> x = getInterForQux(q);
    x.useT(x.makeT());
  }

  Inter<?> getInterForQux(Qux q) {
    if( someTest(q) ) {
      return (Inter<Integer>) mkAnInterInt();
    } else {
      return (Inter<Double>) mkAnInterDouble();
    }
  }
}
```

Javac gives me the error:

> useT(capture#478 of ?) in Inter<capture#478 of ?> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Object)

Whereas Eclipse gives me:

> The method useT(capture#1-of ?) in the type Inter<capture#1-of ?> is
>   not applicable for the arguments
>   (capture#2-of ?)

Obviously, no matter what `T` is the result type of `makeT()` is the same as the parameter type of `useT()`. Why can't I do this? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use wildcard, compiler can't see that the return type of `x.makeT()` and the parameter type of `x.useT()` are the same. In order to guarantee that they are the same, you should use generic method here:

```
public class Foo { 
    public <T> void bar(Inter<T> x) { 
        x.useT(x.makeT()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The actual case is not so trivial, as noted above. For one thing, `bar` is actually an interface method, so I can't just stick a type quantifier on it. But I think you can always refactor the code to make room for the quantifier by pushing the "scope" of T into a private method.

Answer (score 1):

This is logical, since `Inter<?>.makeT()` can return anything, and `Inter<?>.useT(..)` consumes anything, but the two *anythings* can be different.

That would fix it:

```
public <T> void bar(Inter<T> x) {
    x.useT(x.makeT());
}
```

Comment: It's not logical at all: `x` can only have one type and one type variable. But your suggestion is correct.

Comment: it is - the generic types are erased at runtime.

Comment: Yes, and obviously the compiler can't make use of anything that's not available at runtime.

Comment: indeed - you might search for "type erasure"

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture helper:

```
public void bar(Qux q) {
    Inter<?> x = getInterForQux(q);
    barPrivate(x);
}
private <T> void barPrivate(Inter<T> x) {
    x.useT(x.makeT());
}
```

This gives you the same signature for `bar` as you want